# Parsing HTML using BS4 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a website with the following HTML.

I am using Python and BeautifulSoup.

How do I extract the text Texas Rangers out of this?

I am having trouble since it is not in a class?
Thanks,

Matt

```
<div class="team">
            <span class="team-logo mlb tex"></span>Texas Rangers
                            <br />
                <a class="fancy" href="/split_stats/index/Baseball/Pitcher/107">BvP</a>
                &middot;


                                <a class="fancy" href="/split_stats/index/Baseball/Righty/107">vs. R/a>
                &middot;

                <a class="fancy" href="/split_stats/index/Baseball/Away/107">Away</a>
                &middot;

                                <a class="fancy" href="/split_stats/index/Baseball/Night/107">Night</a>

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

May not be the best solution but this works.

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlCode)
>>> soup.div.contents[2].strip()
u'Texas Rangers'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following code that I ran within ipython:

```
In [28]: htmldoc = """<div class="team">
   ....: <span class="team-logo mlb tex"></span>Texas Rangers
   ....: <br />
   ....: <a class="fancy" href="/split_stats/index/Baseball/Pitcher/107">BvP</a>
   ....: &middot;
   ....: <a class="fancy" href="/split_stats/index/Baseball/Righty/107">vs. R/a&gt;
   ....: &middot;
   ....: </a><a class="fancy" href="/split_stats/index/Baseball/Away/107">Away</a>
   ....: &middot;
<   ....: <a class="fancy" href="/split_stats/index/Baseball/Night/107">Night</a>
   ....: </div>
   ....: """

In [30]: soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldoc)

In [31]: import re

In [32]: soup(text=re.compile('Texas Rangers'))
Out[32]: [u'Texas Rangers\n']
```

Comment: The whole point of beautiful soup is to parse HTML pages. If the text were to be different (something other than 'Texas Rangers') then your code would not work.